# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xXXXXXXXX in tid XXXX (RenderThread)

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Sometimes my app will suddenly crash while running normally and leave this error. But I've never used any native code, and I've never actively created threads (but I did use the `rememberCoroutineScope()` and `LaunchEffect()` provided by Jetpack Compose and `viewModelScope`). I found many issues similar to mine, but **none** of them were the same as my error message. Here's my logcat:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xafc3dffc in tid 6832 (RenderThread)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus2/OnePlus2:6.0.1/MMB29M/1447841200:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 6780, tid: 6832, name: RenderThread  >>> com.sample.mysample <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xafc3dffc
    eax ae87e200  ebx c5b57388  ecx 00000001  edx af6af700
    esi ae87e580  edi 00000000
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
    eip c5b1bdef  ebp 00000000  esp afc3e000  flags 00010286
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00078def  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #01 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #02 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #03 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #04 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #05 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #06 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #07 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #08 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #09 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #10 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #11 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #12 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #13 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #14 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #15 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #16 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #17 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #18 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #19 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #20 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #21 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #22 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #23 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #24 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #25 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #26 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #27 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #28 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #29 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #30 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #31 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #32 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #33 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #34 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #35 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #36 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #37 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #38 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #39 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #40 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #41 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #42 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #43 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #44 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #45 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #46 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #47 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #48 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #49 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #50 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #51 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #52 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #53 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #54 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #55 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #56 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #57 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #58 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #59 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #60 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #61 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #62 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
    #63 pc 0007910b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_08
AM write failed: Broken pipe
```

This crash occurred in `RenderThread` but not `GL`'s error. `GL` is **not** mentioned in my error message, **no** reason for the error is output, and the errors **all** occur in `/system/lib/libhwui.so`

I can't find any situations like mine. What should I do?

Comment: Hi @korita, did you got any solution, I too stuck on same issue.

Comment: @SathishKumar Nope :(
My solution is that don't use Jetpack Compose